# Alert when task is due

Tags: workflow, alert

Is this something I can do in SP13?

I created a task and I want the assigned to be notified via email days before the due date.
Please let me know if there's any article I can read or a workaround I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article By Laura Rogers to create a workflow that reminds you a week before an item is due.
http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=64